# Some questions about harmonic functions

Tags: harmonic-functions

-Assume $u$ is a harmonic function on $\mathbb{R}^3$, and assume u(x,y,z)=1+x  when $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$. What is the value $u(0,0,0)$?

I am in doubt between $1$ and $0$, could it be both?

-Let $V(r)$ be a radial harmonic function in $\mathbb{R}^3$; which is the ODE for V?

My answer:
$$V'' + \frac 2 r V' = 0, \quad \text{for} \quad r>0. $$

are they correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your answer to the second part is correct.  For the firwt part, the value of a harmonic function at the center of the surface is equal to the average of its value over that surface.  By symmetry, that average value is 1, so that's your answer.